# Is it possible to send a request from the server to retrieve data from the application when it is minimized?

Tags: react-native

I need to get location data from one device when requested by another device (even if the device from which I want location is not on foreground).

I've seen somewhere an implementation of sending device location while the application is not active via setInterval, but it's very resource intensive and not practical. So, is there any way to get the location of another device which is not open at the moment and is in quit or foreground state?

Comment: Would something like this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45108823/handle-silent-push-notification-in-closed-react-native-app-android

Comment: I need to send the app location to the server, while the app is quit or in the background